# LMH664 - Buffer Configuration

Tags: operational-amplifier, texas-instruments

I am trying to use LMH6642MAX op amplifier in the inverting closed loop configuration (gain 3.5) for a periodic square input signal 20 kHz (2 Volts High, 0 Volts Low). The problem comes when I checked the ouput and I find that the output signal rings. When the input is low the output swings around 0 V and when is high it oscillates around 7 Volts.

My first thought was that the problem was coming from the power supply but I have added two decoupling capacitors in the positive rail of the op-amp, but it didn't fix the problem. The datasheet doesn't say the magnitude of the decoupling capacitor but I have used 0.01uF and 2.2uF because they have worked very well for similar op-amps.

My second thought was that the op-amp was unstable working at that frequency. That's is, the gain is 1 and the phase between the input and output is 180 degrees. However, after inspecting the datasheet, it seems that the open-loop gain reaches 0 dB when the frequency of the signal is of the order 100 Mhz.

I am running out of ideas about what could be the root cause of this ringing.

[image]

Comment: what is attached to the output that you are not showing ? capacitance?

Comment: [CH 11.1](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmh6642.pdf?ts=1635788123543&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLMH6642) explains about parasitic capacitances possibly causing ringing.  Is this on a breakboard or PCB?

Comment: It is in a PCB and there is no output connected yet. Maybe is this the cause of the ring? I have simulated the circuit (output not connected) with LTSpice and I don't see the ring.

Comment: I am using the single-channel op amp.

Comment: Yes sorry. I was misled by the name.. I am out of ideas. Could you post a scope shot of the ringing ? It could be that 2.5k feedback resistance is already somewhat large for a really fast opamp. In that case, you should add a small capacitor across that feedback resistor. Something on the order of 10 pF would suffice.

Comment: Just found the cause of the ringing. It was the capacitance from the oscilloscope probe. When the ground from the oscilloscope is not connected then it doesn't show the. Chapter 2 of this document [link] (https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa367c/snoa367c.pdf?ts=1635793735182) says: "Parasitic, or loading, capacitance directly on the output is particularly effective at transforming amplifiers
into oscillators". I guess that the capacitance of the probe is enough to make the op-amp oscillate.

Comment: I don't think that the amp was ever oscillating in that case. The oscillation only happens in your scope probes when the ground lead forms a long loop. If your want to probe signals with sudden edges, proper low inductance attachment of the return lead is important.

Answer (score -1):

when your OPAMP is powered with a single power supply, you have to make a Vcc/2 voltage to provide a mid-voltage on inputs of OPAMP.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBK6Qr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: -1 neither does this explain the ringing, nor is the op trying to amplify a gnd referenced signal that would require a dc level shift, nor is your schematic the usual way to do it ( I am not sure it would even work)

Comment: @tobalt missing a proper DC reference for OPAMP always cause unpredictable problems including instability . By the way, what exactly would you do for a single supply OPAMP to bias correctly? It's been working for me hundred times. So I know what I said.

Comment: Op says that it is also unstable for the high input where everything is properly biased. in your circuit R3/4 have way too high impedance to set a stable midpoint reference. as a result, gain will not be 2 but will vary based on input voltage.. that high midpoint impedance also allows positive feedback which invites noise at best, instability at worst.

Comment: also, that opamp have common voltage input range below the negative supply and rail-to-rail output, so no problem with the function desired by the OP

Comment: @tobalt My circuit is for AC signals and not for DC precision signals. with C2 the effect of impedance of R3 and R4 will be removed. of course generally, impedance of R3 R4 should be lower, I just meant a general idea with these values in the circuit. The 100k would never make any positive feedback and stability at all.